# Plotting Laplace's Equation

Tags: plotting, summation

Currently, I am trying to plot out the below equation using Mathematica.

$$Z(\rho, \phi) = 50 +\frac{200}{\pi} \sum_{odd \; m}^\infty \bigg(\frac{\rho}{a} \bigg)^m \frac{\sin (m\phi) }{m}$$

Or, if one wants, I could also rewrite the above equation as the one shown below.

$$Z(\rho, \phi) = 50 +\frac{200}{\pi} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{\rho}{a} \bigg)^{2m+1} \frac{\sin ((2m+1)\phi) }{2m+1}$$

Note that the $a$ value in the equations above stands for the radius (i.e. $\rho$) specific to my given circle.

I have attempted to write the below Mathematica code to plot out the distribution shown in the equation but to no avail.

```
nmax=40;
f[n_] := 50 + 200/Pi +
  Sum[ (Rho/a)^(2n+1) Sin[(2n+1)Phi]/(2n+1), {n, 0, nmax}];
  
 Plot[{f[nTerms, a]}, {a, 0, 2}]
```

Note that I made the minor substitution of $m$ to $n$ for my above code. That aside, I am quite certain that I did the `Plot` section very incorrectly.

If possible, I would greatly appreciate it if anybody in the community could show and help me correctly plot for the given distribution shown in the equations above. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = a > 0 && ρ > 0;

z[ρ_, ϕ_, a_ : 1, nmax_ : 40] := 
  50 + 200/Pi + 
   Sum[(ρ/a)^(2 n + 1) Sin[(2 n + 1) ϕ]/(2 n + 1), {n, 0, nmax}];

Plot3D[z[ρ, ϕ], {ρ, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, Pi},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 5] // Quiet
```

[image]

If the number of terms is infinite

```
f = z[ρ, ϕ, a, Infinity] // 
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify

(* (1/(4 π))(800 + 
  200 π - π ArcTan[
    a - ρ Cos[ϕ], -ρ Sin[ϕ]] + π ArcTan[
    a - ρ Cos[ϕ], ρ Sin[ϕ]] - π ArcTan[
    a + ρ Cos[ϕ], -ρ Sin[ϕ]] + π ArcTan[
    a + ρ Cos[ϕ], ρ Sin[ϕ]]) *)

Plot3D[Evaluate[
   f /. a -> 1], {ρ, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, Pi},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I did try copying your line of code onto the Mathematica on my device to see how it worked out; however, the plot refused to show up - only allowing an empty but interactive box to show on the screen. I did try to retype the entire code while writing ϕ as `\[CurlyPhi]` and ρ as `"esc" rho "esc"`. Unfortunately, the problem persists. Do you perhaps have any idea why this "empty plot" problem exists? Is it perhaps due to the fact that I only have a "basic" plan on Mathematica?

Comment: Try restarting Mathematica then copy and paste the code into a new notebook.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! While it did take a couple more attempts, I was able to get it working once more. Beyond that, thank you for your comprehensive post!